# How to accept JSON in Absinthe GraphQL requests

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, absinthe

I'm attempting to receive a string of JSON in my graphql implementation but keep getting errors with the custom scalar I've defined to handle the JSON.

I've defined a custom scalar to properly serialize the JSON to an elixir map. I'm getting errors that I have invalid data types before my code reaches the parsing stage of the custom scalar. I'm attempting to use https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe/wiki/Scalar-Recipes#json-using-jason to create the scalar however I've modified to use Poison instead of Jason.

My absinthe mutator using the :json scalar type I created.

```
@desc "Update user"
field :update_user, type: :user do
  arg(:email, :string)
  arg(:password, :string)
  arg(:first_name, :string)
  arg(:last_name, :string)
  arg(:age, :integer)
  arg(:client_store, :json)

  resolve(handle_errors(&Resolvers.User_Resolver.update_user/3))
end
```

My scalar definition and graphql schema definition

```
    scalar :json, name: "Json" do
        description("""
        The `Json` scalar type represents arbitrary json string data, represented as UTF-8
        character sequences. The Json type is most often used to represent a free-form
        human-readable json string.
        """)
        serialize(&encode/1)
        parse(&decode/1)
    end

    # @spec decode(Absinthe.Blueprint.Input.String.t) :: {:ok, :string} | :error
    # @spec decode(Absinthe.Blueprint.Input.Null.t) :: {:ok, nil}
    defp decode(%Absinthe.Blueprint.Input.String{value: value}) do
        Logger.info "decoded input value:"
        case Poison.decode(value) do
        {:ok, result} -> {:ok, result}
        _ -> :error
        end
    end

    defp decode(%Absinthe.Blueprint.Input.Null{}) do
        {:ok, nil}
    end

    defp decode(_) do
        :error
    end

    defp encode(value), do: value

    object :user do
        field(:id, :id)
        field(:email, :string)
        field(:password, :string)
        field(:first_name, :string)
        field(:last_name, :string)
        field(:age, :integer)
        field(:client_store, :json)
    end
```

when sending the following queries:

```
    mutation updateUser{
      updateUser(client_store: "{"key":"value"}"){
        id
      }
    }
```

I receive a `syntax error before: \"\\\":\\\"\"`

```
    mutation updateUser{
      updateUser(client_store: "hello"){
        id
      }
    }
```

I receive a `"Argument \"client_store\" has invalid value \"hello\"`

Sending the GraphQL query through a unit test via `Phoenix.ConnTest`

```
query = """
    mutation updateUser{
      updateUser(client_store: "{\"key\":\"value\"}"){
        id
      }
    }
  """

res =
  context.conn
  |> put_req_header("content-type", "text")
  |> put_req_header("authorization", token)
  |> post("/api", query)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with your mutation, you need to escape the quotes inside the string, like this:

```
mutation updateUser{
  updateUser(client_store: "{\"key\": \"value\"}"){
    id
  }
}
```

Otherwise, the interpretation is that the second quote marks the end of the string, so you basically have the string `"{"` followed by `key":"value"}"`, which is syntatically invalid.

Note that when sending the mutation in an unit test, you are defining the mutation as a string already, so you need to further escape the quotes:

```
query = """
    mutation updateUser{
      updateUser(client_store: "{\\\"key\\\":\\\"value\\\"}"){
        id
      }
    }
  """
```

This may be a little tricky to understand at first, but printing it makes it clearer:

```
iex(1)> """
...(1)>     mutation updateUser{
...(1)>       updateUser(client_store: "{\"key\":\"value\"}"){
...(1)>         id
...(1)>       }
...(1)>     }
...(1)> """ |> IO.puts()
    mutation updateUser{
      updateUser(client_store: "{"key":"value"}"){
        id
      }
    }

iex(2)> """
...(2)>     mutation updateUser{
...(2)>       updateUser(client_store: "{\\\"key\\\":\\\"value\\\"}"){
...(2)>         id
...(2)>       }
...(2)>     }
...(2)> """ |> IO.puts() 
    mutation updateUser{
      updateUser(client_store: "{\"key\":\"value\"}"){
        id
      }
    }
```

So the last one works because when the string is evaluated, the result is the original mutation, which escapes the quotes.

Comment: Running `mutation updateUser{
          updateUser(client_store: "{\"key\": \"value\"}"){
            id
          }
        }`

produces: `syntax error before: \"\\\": \\\"\"`

unfortunately.

Comment: How are you sending the mutation? Through GraphiQL?

Comment: Sending through `Phoenix.ConnTest` in a unit test. I'll include the way I send in the question for visibility.

Comment: Ok I've got it working through GraphiQL. Not sure what's wrong with the unit test. I will post when i'm done. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your problem in the unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing like this

```
  test "should get an existing key" do
    {:ok, user} = Api.Auth.Users.create_user(%{name: "Test User"})
    {:ok, app} = Api.Auth.Apps.create_app(%{owner_id: %{type: :user, id: user.id}, name: "name"})
    {:ok, key} = Api.Auth.Keys.create_key(%{app_id: app.id})

    %{resp_body: response} =
      build_conn()
      |> post("graphql", %{
        "query" => """
          query {
            key(id: "#{key.id}") {
              id
            }
          }
        """
      })

    %{"data" => %{"key" => %{"id" => id}}} = Jason.decode!(response)

    assert key.id == id
  end
end
```